# Oracle Apex 5 action button next to row

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I am new to Apex 5 and need some help. I am trying to build a simple application. I have a search field which selects data from a table. when the rows are returned I would like to have a button next to each row. I will try and explain what the button should do.

Let's use stock as an example. the row will contain a name and a number in stock, lets say items in stock is 10. When I press the button another report below should then open and add the name and a count of 1 for the row where the button was clicked and also reduce the count to 9 from the top row. If I click the button again the count should change on the bottom row to 2 and to 8 on the top row.

Here is where the other problem comes in. If I do a new search for a new item, it should still keep the below selected items and I should be able to click the button to add the new items to the bottom list. Only once I have selected everything should the submit button be pressed to do something.

I am not even able to paste any code as I have mostly tried just using the processes and dynamic actions. I am totally stuck with this. :|

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO and welcome to apex. I'll start right off and mention the obvious: you're just new to apex and you already want to deepdive into it. I respect your eagerness, though you should take care of not stumbling more than actually walking before you attempt to run. What have you yourself actually been trying? How much of the apex concepts do you understand? It seems you've searched in the right direction, with DA's and processes, but where have you actually stumbled down? Shouldn't all changes made be temporary until confirmed?

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you for the welcome. I understand the concept of how Apex works, I have created a few reports and pages with various buttons to do something. I have tried to run processes to update a new page when I select a dropdown box for instance. it will then add an item to a new page which does not work for me as I need to have it on the same page. effectively the app should sift though thousands of items and select some things and do something later on. Yes changes should be temporary but once I start a new search it resets the search page (bottom table)

Comment: that being said, it was based on searches, I could not get the actual button to display next to each row either.

Comment: Anyone able to assist? :(